# redirect sub directory of apache svn (mod_dav_svn)

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, mod-dav-svn

I've got a mod_dav_svn apache webserver serving up a big tree of svn. I need to move a sub tree to a new server (not svn). Is there any way to use some kind of rewrite to redirect all of the sub tree so people visiting old URLs will be redirected to the new URLs?

Example my tree is like this

```
folder
  a
    file1.html
    file2.html
  b
    file3.html
    file4.html
```

I can currently access these, served by mod_dav_svn at

```
http://svn.server/svn/folder/a/
http://svn.server/svn/folder/a/file1.html
http://svn.server/svn/folder/a/file2.html
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/file3.html
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/file4.html
```

I want to copy `b` to some other server so that those files are accessible at new URLs. eg.

```
http://new.server/someplace/b/
http://new.server/someplace/b/file3.html
http://new.server/someplace/b/file4.html
```

And I want redirects from the old places to redirect to the new places

```
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/           -> http://new.server/someplace/b/
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/file3.html -> http://new.server/someplace/b/file3.html
http://svn.server/svn/folder/b/file4.html -> http://new.server/someplace/b/file4.html
```

The problem is, mod_dav_svn is controlling everything below `/svn` on `svn.server`  Is there a way to configure apache or mod_dav_svn to do this redirect of the `b` subfolder ond the old server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to redirect before `mod_dav_svn` takes over.

```
Redirect permanent /svn/folder/b/ http://new.server/someplace/b/
```